# Unable to find TextBox Control in the ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I'm unable to find the textbox control in a gridview. And the below code is always returning NULL

**HTML**:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                margin-left: 0px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &#160;&#160;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    SkillColumn1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
            <tr style="width: 100%">
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <asp:TextBox  ID="txt_Skill1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Skill1_value") %>'
                            CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBoxNew" Width="35%" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

**Entire Mark up**:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLocView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0"
                Width="100%" BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                EmptyDataText="No Data Available" 
                onrowdatabound="gvLocView_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>                      
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                                margin-left: 0px">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        &#160;&#160;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        Location
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                    <td style="width: 50%">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Location") %>' CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBoxNew" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="14%" />
                        <ItemStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                                margin-left: 0px">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &#160;&#160;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        Quarter
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                    <td style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuarter" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quarter") %>' CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBoxNew" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="13%" />
                        <ItemStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                                margin-left: 0px">
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &#160;&#160;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        SkillColumn1
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                    <asp:TextBox  ID="txt_Skill1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Skill1_value") %>'
                                            CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBoxNew" Width="35%" />                                           
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="9%" />
                        <ItemStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>  <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                                margin-left: 0px">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &#160;&#160;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        SkillColumn2
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr style="width: 100%">                                     
                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Skill2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Skill2_value") %>'
                                            CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBox" Width="35%" />
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="9%" />
                        <ItemStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                                margin-left: 0px">
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &#160;&#160;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        SkillColumn3
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Skill3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Skill3_value") %>'
                                            CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBox" Width="35%" />
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>  
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="9%" />
                        <ItemStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                                margin-left: 0px">
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &#160;&#160;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        SkillColumn4
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Skill4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Skill4_value") %>'
                                            CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBox" Width="35%" />
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>   
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="9%" />
                        <ItemStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                                margin-left: 0px">
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &#160;&#160;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        SkillColumn5
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                    <td style="width: 25%">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Skill5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Skill5_value") %>'
                                            CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBox" Width="35%" />
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>   
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="9%" />
                        <ItemStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                                margin-left: 0px">
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &#160;&#160;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">
                                        SkillColumn6
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>                               
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                   <td style="width: 25%">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Skill6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Others") %>'
                                            CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBox" Width="35%" />
                                    </td>                                       
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="9%" />
                        <ItemStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;
                                margin-left: 0px">
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &#160;&#160;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                   <td align="center">
                                        Total
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
                                <tr style="width: 100%">
                                    <td style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Total") %>' CssClass="tms-secondaryRowTextBoxNew" />
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>   
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Width="9%" />
                        <ItemStyle BorderColor="#013963" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle CssClass="tms-primaryRow_new" />
                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="tms-gridViewHeader_fy11"
                    HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

**Codebehind**:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        int counter=0;

        for (int j = 1,col=2; j <= 7; j++,col++)
        {
            TextBox t = (TextBox)e.Row.Cells[col].FindControl("txt_Skill" + j.ToString());

            if (t != null)
            {
                t = e.Row.FindControl("txt_Skill" + j.ToString()) as TextBox;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strSkillArray[counter]))
                    t.Text = strSkillArray[counter].ToString();
            }                
        }
    }
```

**Exception**:

> System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
>   Message="DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a
>   property with the name 'Skill1_value'."   Source="System.Web"
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259   StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String expression)
>          at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.Eval(String expression)
>          at ASP.location_aspx._*DataBinding*_control53(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\ABC\Location.aspx:line 251
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind()
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState
>   rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[]
>   fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind()
>          at Location.UpgradeAccount() in d:\ABC\Location.aspx.cs:line 368
>          at Location.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\ABC\Location.aspx.cs:line 70
>          at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException:

Comment: You are looking for a Textbox in the header template when its in the ItemTemplate! e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header should be ItemTemplate

Comment: if you like to have an answer please paste full relevant markup, the event under scrutiny and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I was trying to assign these datatable headers: Location  Q   Dotnet  Java  Mainframe  Testing  Databases  Others  Total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception has nothing to do with the codebehind you posted. The page cannot bind your grid to whatever DataSource you gave it because it cannot find Skill1_value in your DataSource.

Comment: Hi, I agree with your comment. But here i'm trying to assign txt_Skill1 Textbox control text as 'Dotnet'. For this i'm unable to assign the same. How to assign??

Comment: Your databinding is not working. If `if (e.Row.RowType == RowType.DataRow)` isn't ever returning `true`, seeking the textbox in the header row will not help.

Comment: @sukumar i agree with sq33G that your datasource is empty and there is no row at all

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in HeaderTemplate. You have to use `DataControlRowType.DataRow` to find the row type.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    int counter=0;

    for (int j = 1,col=2; col <= 7; j++,col++,counter++)
    {
        TextBox t = (TextBox)e.Row.Cells[col].FindControl("txt_Skill" + j.ToString());
        if (t != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strSkillArray[counter]))
                t.Text = strSkillArray[counter].ToString();
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use DataRow, Execution is not going inside IF. So i changes to headerRow.

Comment: Please can you provide code for the same. Still i'm not able to find the textbox control. kindly help

Comment: The IF condition e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow  is returning false and not going inside. manually i tried to drag inside the if but still nothing helped.

Comment: Getting again exception: System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code. DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Skill1_value'.

Answer (score -1):

Your texbox is in Itemptemplate and you are searching in header template that's why

Please update your code as per below

change if condition

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```

code to find textbox

```
 TextBox txt_Skill= (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txt_Skill");
```

Comment: The IF condition e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow is returning false and not going inside. manually i tried to drag the execution debug pointer inside the IF but still nothing resolved.

Comment: Getting again exception:

System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code.


DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Skill1_value'.